# Is it possible to open a second shell session that will remember the user, machine, and directory I am in?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, session

I'm ssh'ed into a machine and logged in as a different user.  Is it possible to open a few new windows that will still be ssh'ed into that same machine, still logged in as that user?

Comment: Which OS is the local machine and which terminal software are you using? On Windows, using PuTTY, I click the system menu and select Duplicate Session.

Comment: @Ross: Yes, I started answering this assuming you were SSHing from OS X to linux, but I just realized I might have that backwards.

Comment: In your first window you could start [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) and then start as many different things as you want within screen.

Comment: Oh `screen`, how I love thee!

Comment: excellent, Josh assumed ssh to linux, Nifle assumed ssh to Mac. Either way, problem solved B-)

Comment: I was being vague as I would like to do this on both linux and macos, in any bash shell connected to any machine I happen to be on.  That is a good start Josh, will be handy at work when i'm always on macos.     @Zoredache, if screen works as you say, make it an answer and i will accept it.  @Dennis, that's very cool and somewhat ironic that a windows app can do that.

Comment: @Ross: Check out [some hidden features of screen](http://serverfault.com/questions/81544/hidden-features-of-screen) -- it's a great program!

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70614/gnu-screen-survival-guide

Answer (score 1):

Please note, this answer assumes your local machine is OS X, which you didn't specify...

You could set up a Terminal command to do this. From the **Terminal** menu, choose **Preferences...**. On the "Settings" tab, either create a new settingh group using the **+** button, or duplicate one of the setting groups you like. On the "Shell" group of your new settings, enter as the command: `ssh user@host`, where *user* and *host* are real values. Check the "Run inside shell" box.

[image: OS X Terminal Preferences]

Now, you can open new windows or tabs by choosing the menu options **Shell > New Window > *Your setting name***  or **Shell > New Tab > *Your setting name***.

**EDIT**: I see you're interested in screen. This is a great program, and I use in all the time. In fact the screenshot above is outdated. What I now have is the one above it, called "Resume Screen". The command for that one is:

```
ssh -t user@host screen -RR -DD
```

This will connect to `host` as `user` and resume the last screen you were using (detaching it if you're still attached elsewhere). Similar means of setting up a terminal exist on linux. For gnome-terminal, check **Edit > Profiles**.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to have a local x-server and enable<sup>**(*)**</sup> ssh X forwarding. That way you could start any app (including a terminal) remotely and have it displayed locally.

(*) I believe it's turned on by default on most command line ssh clients