# Ubuntu - Clone Terminal Window with SSH Connection

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, centos

I've used some windows `SSH` programs, which allow me to spawn new windows based on my current SSH connection.

Is there an easy way to "clone" my terminal window that is connected to a different machine via SSH? I'm hoping to avoid launch multiple windows and logging into each one.

I'm doing this on `Ubuntu` but would prefer a general `Linux` solution, as I'd like to be able to do it from `CentOS` and other flavors too. If there is something better than the `terminal window`, I'm game too, as long as I can do a `yum` install of it :)

Comment: The second part of [my answer in this question](http://superuser.com/questions/620532/how-to-have-multiple-windows-in-a-ssh-terminal-session/620534#620534) may be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a screen multiplexer such as [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) (and I would recommend using [Byobu](http://byobu.co/) on top of one of those), this can be done quite easily.

With tmux, you would do something like the following to open up an existing session:

```
tmux attach-session
```

And that will open up and attach to the most recently used session (as gleaned from the [man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tmux&sektion=1)).

Comment: Is not the question about opening a new SSH session according to the existing one?